# How can I get DC/OS to see the Universe repo

Tags: vagrant, dcos

I'm trying to get DCOS running with Vagrant 1.8.4 and VirtualBox.  DCOS comes up and I can get to the dashboard, but I cannot see the "Universe" repo.  The computer on which DC/OS Vagrant is running is behind a proxy, so I followed the directions [here](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.8/administration/installing/custom/configure-proxy/), but I still see the following error:

```
[object Object] You can go to the Repositories Settings page to change installed repositories.
```

The master node can reach the outside world, in particular I can (vagrant) ssh into the master node and successfully ping machines outside the proxy.

Finally, as an alternative I've tried downloading and setting up a local repo, but encountered a [known issue](https://dcosjira.atlassian.net/browse/DCOS-323).

A similar question has been asked (as a stackoverflow beginner I've exhausted my link budget) about difficulty finding the Universe when there are two repos, but that doesn't seem applicable to the issue I'm facing.

Any advice would be appreciated.  Thank you for your time.

As an addendum here is some more information from recent tests: On my host laptop (A Mac) I can ping both google.com and mesosphere.com.  However, when I vagrant ssh into the master node, I can ping google.com, but when I try to ping mesosphere.com, I see the error:

```
ping: unknown host mesosphere.com
```

Naively I would assume that since the Universe repo lives at universe.mesosphere.com, I would need to resolve mesosphere.com.

Answer (score 4):

After a bit of digging it seems the file cosmos reads the proxy config from changed in DC/OS 1.8 from `/var/lib/dcos/environment.proxy` to `/opt/mesosphere/etc/proxy.env`

Try running the following commands:

```
cp /var/lib/dcos/environment.proxy /opt/mesosphere/etc/proxy.env
systemctl restart dcos-cosmos
```

---- Edit -----

Bug to track the documentation being updated https://dcosjira.atlassian.net/browse/DCOS-398

Comment: I tried what you suggested and the error changed to 

    undefined You can go to the Repositories Settings page to change installed repositories.

As a further experiment I updated /opt/mesosphere/etc/mesos-slave-common on the public and private agents and restarted the appropriate tasks, that didn't seem to make a difference.

Thank you for your suggestion, by the way.

Comment: After finding a fixing a problem with my proxy settings I now get the message "Unexpected down stream http error: GET https://universe.mesosphere.com/repo 403"

Comment: @MatthewCalef happy to help. Is it possible that the proxy you're hitting is blocking the request? The url https://universe.mesosphere.com/repo doesn't have any auth in front of it, so the 403 Forbidden response isn't coming from the unvierse side. You may need to contact the admin of your proxy.  Also note, that the dcos cluster will also need to be able to download from https://downloads.mesosphere.com in order to get the CDN'd response.

Answer (score 0):

DC/OS 1.8.4 added a new way to configure a proxy at install time in config.yaml. Unfortunately there was [a bug](https://github.com/dcos/dcos/pull/734) with it that's been fixed on master and will be in DC/OS 1.8.5.

DC/OS proxy docs: https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/administration/installing/custom/configuration-parameters/#use_proxy

DC/OS Vagrant proxy docs: https://github.com/dcos/dcos-vagrant/blob/master/docs/configure.md#configure-a-proxy

For posterity, there are new fields:

- `use_proxy` (boolean)
- `http_proxy` (string)
- `https_proxy` (string)
- `no_proxy` (array of strings)